# Help understanding code snippet (AABB collision)

Tags: c#

I've snatched this piece of tile collision code from another game, but in the spirit of understanding and not just stealing, I'd like to get some help understanding what exactly it does. Specifically what the function of x1, y1, x2, y2 are and why it picks start and end one tile outside the actual bounding box of the object.

```
...
    ...
        Int32 Tile.Size = 16;
    ...
...

...
    private Vector2 CheckTileCollision(Vector2 velocity)
    {
        // Find all the tiles we intersect with, including a layer outside.
        Int32 startx = (Int32)((Single)this.Left / Tile.Size) - 1;
        Int32 endx = (Int32)((Single)this.Right / Tile.Size) + 1;
        Int32 starty = (Int32)((Single)this.Top / Tile.Size) - 1;
        Int32 endy = (Int32)((Single)this.Bottom / Tile.Size) + 1;

        // The following are array positions, not world positions.
        Int32 x1 = -1; // Only set when there's a horizontal collision
        Int32 y1 = -1; // Only set when there's a horizontal collision
        Int32 x2 = -1; // Only set when there's a vertical collision
        Int32 y2 = -1; // Only set when there's a vertical collision

        Vector2 newVelocity = velocity;
        Vector2 nextPosition = this.position + velocity;

        for (Int32 x = startx; x <= endx; x += 1)
        {
            for (Int32 y = starty; y <= endy; y += 1)
            {
                if (realm.TileAt(x, y).IsSolid) // We only collide with solid tiles.
                {
                    // The world coordinates of a tile.
                    Vector2 tilePosition = new Vector2(x * Tile.Size, y * Tile.Size);

                    // Check if we intersect the tile.
                    if (nextPosition.X + this.Width > tilePosition.X &&
                        nextPosition.X < tilePosition.X + Tile.Size &&
                        nextPosition.Y + this.Height > tilePosition.Y &&
                        nextPosition.Y < tilePosition.Y + Tile.Size)
                    {
                        realm.Tiles[x, y].Debug = true;
                        if (this.Bottom <= tilePosition.Y) // if the bottom is above or touching the tile top
                        {
                            x2 = x; // x2 is set to current tile array position, not world position
                            y2 = y; // y2 is set to current tile array position, not world position

                            if (x2 != x1)
                                newVelocity.Y = tilePosition.Y - (position.Y + this.Height);
                        }
                        else if (this.Right <= tilePosition.X) // if the right side is to the left or touching the tile left
                        {
                            x1 = x; // x1 is set to current tile array position, not world position
                            y1 = y; // y1 is set to current tile array position, not world position

                            if (y1 != y2) 
                                newVelocity.X = tilePosition.X - (position.X + this.Width);
                            if (x2 == x1)
                                newVelocity.Y = this.Velocity.Y;
                        }
                        else if (this.Left >= tilePosition.X + Tile.Size)// if the left side is to the right or touching the tile right
                        {
                            x1 = x; // x1 is set to current tile array position, not world position
                            y1 = y; // y1 is set to current tile array position, not world position

                            if (y1 != y2)
                                newVelocity.X = (tilePosition.X + Tile.Size) - position.X;
                            if (x2 == x1)
                                newVelocity.Y = this.Velocity.Y;
                        }
                        else if (this.Top >= tilePosition.Y + Tile.Size) // if the top is below or touching the tile bottom
                        {
                            x2 = x; // x2 is set to current tile array position, not world position
                            y2 = y; // y2 is set to current tile array position, not world position

                            newVelocity.Y = (tilePosition.Y + Tile.Size) - position.Y;
                            if (y2 == y1)
                                newVelocity.X = this.Velocity.X;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return newVelocity;
}
...
```

**EDIT**

Added a few more comments to the code, and fixed up the ifs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It picks start and end tiles outside of the bounding box of the object because the object could be moving, and has a velocity.

x1, y1, x2, y2 are the outside boundaries of the object, after it has resolved collisions.

The function returns a new velocity of the object that will prevent the object from colliding.

Comment: x1, y2, x2, y2 aren't world coordinates but array indexes, so it's not a bounding box. But I did confirm the extra layer is to prevent the bullet through paper effect.

Comment: Correct, the world position is indicated by `x * Tile.Size`. When we assign x1, y1, x2, and y2 we don't need to do this multiplication because we only care about relative coordinates (object's point of view) not absolute coordinates (world coordinates). So it does seem to be a relative collision bounding box.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Even if the x1, y1, x2, y2 are only relative bounds, it still makes it work. So names that might better be suited are left, right, top, bottom?

Comment: Not quite, x1 and y1 are the (normalized) position of a left/right collision, while x2 and y2 are the same for up/down.
A substitute name might be: `x1: horizontalCollisionXCoord`, `y1: horizontalCollisionYcoord`,`x2: verticalCollisionXCoord`, `y2: verticalCollisionYCoord`. (those names are quite long...).
When iterating through possible collision positions it looks for a wall `(x2==x1)` a floor `(y2==y1)` or a corner. Once it finds one, it resolves the new velocity and continues iterating.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Great work, and definitely worth the upvote and marked it as the answer.